# Is there any good approach available in JavaScript for sorting an object of objects based on some property of the object which holds unique value?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Please refer the below object of objects:

```
var gamesObject = {
    1:{ratingCode: "6", description: "cricket", order: 2},
    4:{ratingCode: "7", description: "football", order: 3},
    10:{ratingCode: "12", description: "chess", order: 4},
    12:{ratingCode: "16", description: "baseball", order: 5},
    13:{ratingCode: "18", description: "hockey", order: 6},
    15:{ratingCode: "10", description: "tennis", order: 7},
    200:{ratingCode: "14", description: "swimming", order: 1}
}
```

I want to sort this object of objects based on the property "order" which holds unique value. is there any good approach available in JavaScript to sort this object of objects?

Comment: Objects cannot be ordered, they're unordered data structures.

Comment: @deceze: They used to be. Then ES2015 came along and messed everythihg up. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder True that, but the rules are so arcane that it's easier to stick to the "unordered" maxim.

Answer (score 3):

While JavaScript objects do have a kind of property order now (as of ES2015), you'd be much better off using an array, for three reasons:

1. Arrays are *meant* for ordered information
2. The way in which JavaScript objects have order now is limited to certain operations
3. The way in which JavaScript objects have order now means your properties will **always** be in the numeric order of your keys, as your keys fit the definition of an array index and so don't follow the rule of being in insertion order

So:

```
var result = Object.keys(gamesObject).map(function(key) {
    return gamesObject[key];
}).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.order - b.order;
});
```

Live Example:

```js
var gamesObject = {
    1:{ratingCode: "6", description: "cricket", order: 2},
    4:{ratingCode: "7", description: "football", order: 3},
    10:{ratingCode: "12", description: "chess", order: 4},
    12:{ratingCode: "16", description: "baseball", order: 5},
    13:{ratingCode: "18", description: "hockey", order: 6},
    15:{ratingCode: "10", description: "tennis", order: 7},
    200:{ratingCode: "14", description: "swimming", order: 1}
};
var result = Object.keys(gamesObject).map(function(key) {
    return gamesObject[key];
}).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.order - b.order;
});
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Or with ES2015+ syntax:

```
let result = Object.keys(gamesObject)
    .map(key => gamesObject[key])
    .sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);
```

Live Example:

```js
var gamesObject = {
    1:{ratingCode: "6", description: "cricket", order: 2},
    4:{ratingCode: "7", description: "football", order: 3},
    10:{ratingCode: "12", description: "chess", order: 4},
    12:{ratingCode: "16", description: "baseball", order: 5},
    13:{ratingCode: "18", description: "hockey", order: 6},
    15:{ratingCode: "10", description: "tennis", order: 7},
    200:{ratingCode: "14", description: "swimming", order: 1}
};
let result = Object.keys(gamesObject)
    .map(key => gamesObject[key])
    .sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

If you need to keep the old key, we can add it as a property of the objects:

```
var result = Object.keys(gamesObject).map(function(key) {
    var entry = gamesObject[key];
    entry.key = key;
    return entry;
}).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.order - b.order;
});
```

Live Example:

```js
var gamesObject = {
    1:{ratingCode: "6", description: "cricket", order: 2},
    4:{ratingCode: "7", description: "football", order: 3},
    10:{ratingCode: "12", description: "chess", order: 4},
    12:{ratingCode: "16", description: "baseball", order: 5},
    13:{ratingCode: "18", description: "hockey", order: 6},
    15:{ratingCode: "10", description: "tennis", order: 7},
    200:{ratingCode: "14", description: "swimming", order: 1}
};
var result = Object.keys(gamesObject).map(function(key) {
    var entry = gamesObject[key];
    entry.key = key;
    return entry;
}).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.order - b.order;
});
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```